# Variable not working android

Tags: java, android, local-variables

I have problem with variable scoretemp. it always return 0. 
Inside if condition it's working.

```
for (final Score score2 : scores) {
  scoretemp = score2.getResult();
}
```

but when i try to get the result in the last line.

```
TV2.setText(""+scoretemp);
```

It always be zero without any reason.

Code:

```
BScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  double scoretemp;

  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    BScore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    sp.play(click, 1, 1, 0  , 0, 1);
    int scoreresult = totalscore;
    final RequestControllerObserver observer2 = new RequestControllerObserver() {
      public void requestControllerDidReceiveResponse(final RequestController requestController) {
        // get the scores from our controller
        final ScoresController scoresController = (ScoresController) requestController;
        final List<Score> scores = scoresController.getScores();
        if(scores!=null){
          for (final Score score2 : scores) {
            scoretemp = score2.getResult();
          }
          // we're done!
          dismissDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
        }
      }
    public void requestControllerDidFail(final RequestController aRequestController, final Exception anException) {
      dismissDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "لا يوجد إتصال بالأنترنت أو خطأ في إستقبال البيانات", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
  };
// set up a ScoresController with our observer
ScoresController scoresController2 = new ScoresController(observer2);
showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
scoresController2.setMode(mode);
scoresController2.loadRangeForUser(Session.getCurrentSession().getUser());
TV2.setText(""+scoretemp);
```

Comment: variables don't work, they vary!

Comment: The callback method requestControllerDidReceiveResponse is called asynchronous, so it can and probably will be called after the TV2.setText(""+scoretemp); is called.

Comment: @RobeEleckers I think it is the issue here. the last line should be inside the listener and not outside of it.

Comment: Why is it 'final'. Looks weird

Comment: It doesnt make sense to have a 'final' iterator in a for loop. Final means that the variable cant be changed once it is set

Comment: @TanjaV That's no problem, you get a fresh `final Score score2` in each iteration (the scope of `score2` is 1 iteration only). It won't work in `for (final int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` since there is only one `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback method requestControllerDidReceiveResponse is called asynchronously, so it can and probably will be called after the TV2.setText(""+scoretemp); is called.

You could either do the update from within the requestControllerDidReceiveResponse method (invoke on GUI thread) or fire some kind of propertychangedevent when the value is changed which is then handled by the GUI thread.